# How to define a custom "This browser is not supported" page in Sails.JS

Tags: sails.js

When I try to use a Sails.js site in production mode with a Safari 5.1, I'm getting a "This browser is not supported" page with a big Sails.JS logo. What's the proper way to customize this page ? . Also, how can I check what rules are applied to allow or block old browsers from using the site?

The website works as expected with modern browsers ( it even works in IE 11 ).

Answer (score 0):

I found it.
It's defined in the layout of the site that was generated from the template file caviar-layout.js . The layout is in /views/layouts

The Layout File includes the image, rules to block browsers and the custom message.